# I am having trouble pushing form values to an array in a leaderboard app

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I am trying to make a small leaderboard app and I am having problems saving the values in the form. When I try to push the information to the array it is empty and I am rendering nothing, Any help would be appreciated.

Also, my local storage isn't working properly any help on that would also be appreciated.

```
    #Javascript

   const form = document.querySelector('.form');
   const scores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('scores')) || [];

    function saveScore() {
    const name = document.querySelector('.fullname').value;
     const score = document.querySelector('.thescore').value;
     const newScore = {
     name,
     score,
     };
     scores.push(newScore);
     localStorage.setItem('scores', JSON.stringify(scores));
     }

     function renderScores() {
     const scoreList = document.querySelector('.result-list');
     scoreList.innerHTML = '';
     scores.forEach((score) => {
     const li = document.createElement('li');
     li.innerHTML = `${score.name} : ${score.score}`;
     scoreList.appendChild(li);
    localStorage.setItem('scores', JSON.stringify(scores));
     });
     }

     form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     saveScore();
     renderScores();
     localStorage.setItem('scores', JSON.stringify(scores));
     });
```

Comment: Can you share the html?

Comment: ok I will share it

Comment: pushing to the array and displaying are two different issues. To verify items are getting pushed to the array log it to console.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `saveScore` function in the eventListener.

This will set the name and score in local storage.

```
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
const scores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('scores')) || [];


form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
// inside now
saveScore();
});

function saveScore() {
const name = document.querySelector('.fullname').value;
const score = document.querySelector('.thescore').value;
const newScore = {
name,
score,
};
scores.push(newScore);
localStorage.setItem('scores', JSON.stringify(scores));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `saveScore();` never happen. Could you try invoke `saveScore();` after `e.prevendDefault()` inside event callback.
Then after event 'submit' will happen you will trigger the saveScore and save values. I hope that will help.

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this:

```
var arr = [];
function saveScore() {
const name = document.querySelector('.fullname').value;
const score = document.querySelector('.thescore').value;
var newScore = {};
newScore.name = name;
newScore.score = score;
arr.push(newScore);
localStorage.setItem('arr', JSON.stringify(scores));
}
```

Comment: thanks ronnie it is working now but I am not exactly sure what I did wrong but now it is working

Comment: any also now guys my local storage isnt working...

Comment: Local storage won't work, as the event listener is not triggered. Check my answer above it will help.